# Creating random points with "CreateRandomPoints_management()" function of ArcPy, with minimum distance

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, random, sample

I've been trying to create random points to sample some locations based, at first, on a field which contains the number of samples I want. 
But when I tried at first, in almost every feature it was sampled less than the number of the field.

Then, I tested another way: since I was writting inside a loop through cursor, and one of the fields of the cursor was the area in hectares, and the number of samples is based on the area of the feature, I decided to calculate out of the field the number of samples, but the result was the same.

Then, I was wondering what could cause this problem, it was when I decided to try to run the function with the `minimum_distance` parameter set to zero, and it worked!

Apparently, what happened is that when I run the function with the `minimum_distance` parameter, if a random point falls near another point within the minimum distance, the point is removed and I cannot get the total number of samples I need.

Here is the part of the code:

```
        if 16 <= x[1] < 25:
            minimum_distance = 100
        elif x[1] > 25:
            minimum_distance = 150
        else:
            minimum_distance = 0

        number_of_samples = int(x[1]/8)
        if number_of_samples == 0:
            number_of_samples = 1
        print(number_of_samples)
        arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(out_path=arcpy.env.workspace,
                                            out_name='samples_{}'.format(x[0]),
                                            constraining_feature_class=negBuf_tal,
                                            number_of_points_or_field=number_of_samples,
                                            minimum_allowed_distance=minimum_distance)
```

Where:

x[0]: unique code of feature (inside a loop through cursor);
x[1]: Area in hectares of feature (inside a loop through cursor);
negBuf_tal: negative buffer area of the feature which the loop is going through (to avoid sampling on borders).
OBS: If after the negative buffer the area "desappears", the area to sample in becomes the area without the buffer itself.

How can I solve this without having to write a while structure or something like this?

Answer (score -1):

Since I had to hurry to finish my project, I decided to write the code into a loop `while`, using the `arcpy.Near_analysis()` function, even though it has increased some lines to the code. 
Here is my solution to this problem (if anyone needs the full code to have a better understanding, I can provide, just add a comment, otherwise in this solution there is only a part of the code):

```
        if 16 <= x[1] < 25:
            minimum_distance = 100
        elif x[1] > 25:
            minimum_distance = 150
        else:
            minimum_distance = 0

        number_of_samples = int(x[1]/8)
        if number_of_samples == 0:
            number_of_samples = 1
        print(number_of_samples)

        list_of_pts = []
        dif = -1
        c = 1
        while dif != 0:
            if dif == -1:
                number_of_samples = number_of_samples
                arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(out_path=arcpy.env.workspace,
                                                    out_name='samples_{}_{}'.format(x[0], c),
                                                    constraining_feature_class=negBuf_tal,
                                                    number_of_points_or_field=number_of_samples,
                                                    minimum_allowed_distance=minimum_distance)

                count_sample = arcpy.GetCount_management('samples_{}_{}'.format(x[0], c))
                dif = number_of_samples - int(count_sample.getOutput(0))
            else:
                number_of_samples = dif
                near = True
                while near:
                    arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(out_path=arcpy.env.workspace,
                                                        out_name='samples_{}_{}'.format(x[0], c),
                                                        constraining_feature_class=negBuf_tal,
                                                        number_of_points_or_field=number_of_samples,
                                                        minimum_allowed_distance=minimum_distance)

                    arcpy.Near_analysis('samples_{}_{}'.format(x[0], c), list_of_pts, minimum_distance)
                    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('samples_{}_{}'.format(x[0], c), "NEAR_FID") as near_cursor:
                        for y in near_cursor:
                            if y[0] != -1:
                                near = True
                                break
                            else:
                                near = False

                count_sample = arcpy.GetCount_management('samples_{}_{}'.format(x[0], c))
                dif = number_of_samples - int(count_sample.getOutput(0))

            samples_tmp = 'samples_{}_{}'.format(x[0], c)
            list_of_pts.append(samples_tmp)
            c = c + 1
        arcpy.Merge_management(list_of_pts, 'samples_{}'.format(x[0]))
```